# How to open a file which name contain unicode code in Lisp(sbcl+slime)?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, common-lisp, filenames, slime

```
(with-open-file (s "~/例子.txt"
                 :external-format :utf-8)
  (print s))
```

result:

```
NIL c-string encoding error:
  the character with code 20363 cannot be encoded.
  [Condition of type SB-INT:C-STRING-ENCODING-ERROR]
```

Example:

in Aquamacs 3.5 with newest slime & sbcl2.0.2:
[image: in Aquamacs3.5 with slime & sbcl]

sbcl in iterm2 can do it:

[image: in iterm2]

Aquamacs itself can open and write filename contains utf-8 correctly, too.

I have tried to add

```
(setq slime-net-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
(set-language-environment "UTF-8")
```

in my aquamacs config file, but it doesn't work.
Please help!

Update:
I have finally found the reason.
When in Iterm2, the command

```
locale
```

gives this output:
[image]

While in Aquamacs open from ui, in eshell it gives:

[image: Result from eshell]

After I added:

```
(setenv "LANG" "en_US.UTF-8")
```

to my Aquamacs config, it works!
Thanks to all who reply to my question!
Below is the links that helps me.

[What the question exactly is](https://bugs.launchpad.net/sbcl/+bug/1737304)

[Resolutions to the question](https://github.com/quicklisp/quicklisp-client/issues/152)

[How to set locale for Emacs open from UI](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10822/locale-when-launching-emacs-app-on-os-x)

Comment: Operating system?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, this works fine on Linux x86_64, do you have :sb-unicode in the `*features*` list?

Comment: I'm using sbcl 2.0.2+ slime + aquamcs in Mac10.15.3

Comment: I'm new to Common Lisp, please tell me how to enable :sb-unicode in the  *features* list?

Comment: Try ir in a terminal with Unicode support, If the problem persists, then best to ask on the SBCL mailing list (or similar) how to use Unicode pathnames on macOS and whether they are supported at all in SBCL on macOS.

Comment: the feature list is described here: http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_featur.htm, basically it informs you about some properties of your CL environment, and when it comes to supporting unicode or not (at least with SBCL), this depends on how it was compiled, as far as I know. Your environment seems to support unicode, based on what is shown in iterm2; you can check if the feature is present simply by typing the variable names in the interpreter (there are asterisks around "features", but StackOverflow understands that as italics). Did you reload aquamacs after you modified the config file?

Comment: Yes, I do have reloa

Comment: You can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add something like:

```
(setenv "LANG" "en_US.UTF-8")
```

to your emacs config.
Explain is at above.